# How to write the constraint matrix for this blending problem?

Tags: linear-programming, constraint

Below is a model for maximizing a utility function, a blending of, 3 ingredients $(A, B,C)$ to obtain  3 mixes of fertilizer, with the recipe given as proportions. Ingredients cost $A=130,\ B=150,\ C=100$, benefit per fertilizer $F1=200, F2=300, F3=150$

|  | Recipe | Resource Availability |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Fertilizer 1** | $A \ge 25 \%$ and $B\le40\%$ | $A=4000$ |
| **Fertilizer 2** | $A \ge 30\%$ and $20\%\le B \le 30%$, and $C\le15\%$ | $B =6000$ |
| **Fertilizer 3** | $C \le 15\%$ | $C=2000$ |

**Model**

Objective:
$$ \max z= 10(7x_{11}+20x_{12}+20x_{13}+2x_{21}+15x_{22}+30x_{23}-8x_{31}+5x_{32}-10x_{33})$$

Constraints

\begin{align}0.75 x_{11}-0.25 x_{12}-0.25 x_{13} &\ge 0\\
-0.40 x_{11}-0.40 x_{12}+0.60 x_{13} &\le 0\\
0.70 x_{21}-0.30 x_{22}+ -0.30 x_{23}&\ge 0\\
-0.20 x_{21}+0.80 x_{22}-0.20 x_{23}&\ge 0\\
-0.30 x_{21}+0.70 x_{22}-0.30 x_{23} &\le 0\\
-0.15 x_{21} -0.15 x_{22} + 0.85 x_{23} &\le 0\\
-0.35 x_{31}+ 0.65 x_{32}-0.35 x_{33} &\ge 0\\
x_{11}+ x_{21}+ x_{31}&\le 4000\\
x_{12}+ x_{22}+ x_{32}&\le 6000\\
x_{13}+ x_{23}+ x_{33}&\le 2000 
\end{align}
$$x_{ij}\ge 0$$

It is uncertain to me how to proceed in building the constraint matrix $CM$, the first seven rows are:

$$CM=\begin{pmatrix}
0.75 & -0.25 & -0.25\\
-0.4 & -0.4 & 0.6\\
0.7 & -0.3 & -0.3\\
-0.2 & 0.8 & -0.2\\
-0.3 & 0.7 & -0.3\\
-0.15 & -0.15 & 0.85\\
-0.35 & 0.65 & -0.35\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then to me, the next row is
$$x_{11}\le 4000-(x_{12}+x_{13})\Rightarrow (1,0,0)\le 4000-(x_{12}+x_{13})$$

So that for all the resource constraints
\begin{pmatrix}
0.75 & -0.25 & -0.25\\
-0.4 & -0.4 & 0.6\\
0.7 & -0.3 & -0.3\\
-0.2 & 0.8 & -0.2\\
-0.3 & 0.7 & -0.3\\
-0.15 & -0.15 & 0.85\\
-0.35 & 0.65 & -0.35\\
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}

But then the right hand side $\mathbf{b}= \begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&0&0&0&0&4000 -(x_{12}+x_{13}) \ldots \end{pmatrix} $ gets nine rows of algebraic expressions, not nice, so what's the right way? Maybe just (1,1,1) the last 3 rows.

There's one last thing about the constraints they look redundant, does that mean the fertilizer mixes are the same or almost the same, so the problem is infeasible?

Comment: You have $10$ constraints and $9$ variables, so your constraint matrix should be $10\times 9$. Also, notice that the trivial zero solution ($x_{ij}=0$ for all $i,j$) is feasible.